# sum of product of all pairs of elements in two arrays

Tags: algorithm, math

If we have two arrays say `A=[1,2,3,4]` and `B=[1,2,3]` we need to find the sum  `1*1+1*2+1*3+2*1+2*2+2*3+3*1+3*2+3*3+4*1+4*2+4*3` ,i.e sum of product of all possible pairs in both arrays which may be of different lenghts.
Of course we can do it in `O(n^2)` but is there any efficient way to do it ?
Thanks.
Also both the arrays have integers in the range `1..m` and `1..n` respectively

Comment: you meant O(n*m) probably

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This can be done in `O(n+m)` time by levying the distributive property of multiplication over addition.

The required sum can be generalized as follows:

```
(A[0]*B[0] + A[1]*B[0] + ... + A[m-1]*B[0]) + (A[0]*B[1] + A[1]*B[1] + ... + A[m-1]*B[1]) + ... + (A[0]*B[n-1] + A[1]*B[n-1] + ... + A[m-1]*B[n-1])
```

Note that in each partial sum, we can factor out the element of `B`. The series then simplifies to

```
(A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[m-1]) * B[0] + (A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[m-1]) * B[1] + ... + (A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[m-1]) * B[n-1]
```

Note that the sum of *all* the elements in `A` is a factor of each term in the above series, which can be factored out to give

```
(A[0] + A[1] + ... + A[m-1]) * (B[0] + B[1] + ... + B[n-1])
```

We can thus compute the sum of elements of both the arrays and multiply them together to obtain the sum of the series.

Answer (score 5):

```
1*1+1*2+1*3+2*1+2*2+2*3+3*1+3*2+3*3+4*1+4*2+4*3
=60

(1+2+3) * (1+2+3+4)
=60
```

Why?

```
sum(B) + 2*sum(B) + 3*sum(B) + 4*sum(B)
sum(B) * sum(A)
```

Answer (score 1):

We can observe following fact:

```
A = [1,2,3,4];
B = [1,2,3];
A * B = 
A[0] * B[0] + A[0] * B[1] + A[0] * B[2]+ .. +
A[3] * B[0] + A[3] * B[1] + A[3] * B[2] =
A[0] * (B[0]+B[1]+B[2]) + .. +
A[3] * (B[0]+B[1]+B[2]) = (A[0] + A[1] + A[2] + A[3]) * (B[0] + B[1] + B[2])
```

Answer (score 0):

As others said, you can rewrite your formula as a product of the sums of your vectors.

I am not sure if your arrays hold arbitrary values in range 1...n or the exact range.
If they hold all elements in range 1...n you can rewrite the `sum of 1...n` as `n*(n+1) / 2`